# Droppable not going to correct spot

Tags: jquery, droppable

I have created an inventory that's styled and since I have added the styling in .css when items are placed back into the inventory they go below the existing items and ruins my box. How can I fix this? *(they basically drop out of one of the borders and into a new one)*

http://jsfiddle.net/BxPjC/

**Note:** removing itembox1, itembox3 and itembox4 seems to fix it however I lose my styling. What could I use to replace the divs used for styling.

```
function itemInSpot(drag_item,spot)
{
var oldSpotItem = $(spot).find('img');
if(oldSpotItem.length>100) {
oldSpotItem.appendTo('.inventholding').draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });
}
var item = $('<img />');
item.attr('src',drag_item.attr('src')).attr('class',drag_item.attr('class')).appendTo(spot)    .draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });
drag_item.remove(); // remove the old object
}

 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").draggable({ revert: 'invalid'});

$(".inventholding").droppable()
$("#pricebox").droppable({ accept: '.price'})
$('#pricebox').droppable({ accept: '.price'});
$('#pricebox,#pricebox,.inventholding').bind('drop', function(ev,ui) {      itemInSpot(ui.draggable,this); });

$('#clone_button').click(function() {
    $('#clone_wrapper div:#pricebox')
        .clone()
    .append('')
    .appendTo($('#clone_wrapper'));
})
});

<div id="container">

<body>
    <div id="clone_wrapper">
        <div class="right">
            <div id="pricebox" style="background: none; width:153px; padding:1px; height:auto; margin 1px; border:1px solid black; 
float:left;">
                <select name="qty">
                    <option value="Each" selected>Each</option>
                    <option value="All"> All</option>
                    <option value="Any 2">Any 2</option>
                    <option value="Any 3">Any 3</option>
                </select>
                <input id="coin" type="text" id="text" name="text_name" style="width: 35px; style=" height: 21px; " maxlength=3 /></h6></div>
</div></div>

<button id="clone_button ">New</button></div>
<div id='inventrightside1'><div id='inventrightside2'><p1><img     src="http://kennenmen.netai.net/images/invent1.png "/></p>

<div class="inventholding " clear:both;">
                <div id="itembox1">
                    <div id="itembox3">
                        <div id="itembox4">
                            <img src="http://images.lasuni.com/icons/lionhat_red.png"   class="price" alt="" />
                            <img src="http://images.lasuni.com/icons/duckring_pink.png" class="price" alt="" />
                            <img src="http://images.lasuni.com/icons/cowboyhat_gold.png" class="price" alt="" />
                            <img src="http://images.lasuni.com/icons/halo_pink.png" class="price" alt="" />
                            <img src="http://images.lasuni.com/icons/cakehat_strawberry.png" class="price" alt="" />
                            <img src="http://images.lasuni.com/icons/ninjaeyemask_pink.png" class="price" alt="" />
                            <img src="http://images.lasuni.com/icons/carnivalmask_blue.png" class="price" alt="" />
                            <img src="http://images.lasuni.com/icons/alienhead_purple.png" class="price" alt="" />
                            <img src="http://images.lasuni.com/icons/skullhead_white.png" class="price" alt="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know what is going wrong. In Chrome everything seems to behave the way it should.

Comment: I'm using chrome myself in the jsfiddle did you place items back into the inventory?

Comment: Ok, I dropped them and they were going back automatically. But you meant dropping them over the box. Got it now.

Comment: Yer its really annoying it wasn't doing this before hand must be something to do with the divs. I tried changing classes to the last box so they would fall into that one but nothing seemed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JS change `.inventholding` to `#itembox4`

http://jsfiddle.net/tzDXq/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/hWabw/

```
            <div id="itembox1">
               <div id="itembox3">
                  <div id="itembox4">
                    ...
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
```

I removed the itemboxes and now it seems to work.

An alternative would be to make the last itembox the target for the drop. Not the surrounding container.

Comment: hmm yer I was hoping to keep the styling though because its to match an in client version that's pre-existing. Otherwise if I just remove the divs I'm in the same position I was in before. I appreciate the help though.

Comment: You should put that into the question. The itemboxes seem pretty obsolete. If you don't know that.

Comment: what would you recommend to replace them? I've been coding for about two weeks now so I'm still learning.

Comment: I have posted another answer that keeps them. I don't know why you need that structure so it is hard to recommend anything. 
For future question I would try to remove everything that is not essential for the question and state that the elements are all needed, etc. This makes answering much more easy.